# Reset button works the second time I click it, not the first

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

This app is a scoring app for my FTC(First Tech Challenge) robot.  I have all the scoring working, and am now working on a reset button, which will reset all variables and scores to zero.

Now, for some reason, when I click the reset button the first time, the Autonomous Score is randomly set to a number.  Its been 5, and its also been 55.  However, when I click reset a second time, it works as I wanted it to.

So, I have no idea where I messed up, and I have looked over the code so many times I think I'm going to explode.

Anyway, if any of you can catch something I missed, That'd be awesome!

Thanks,
-Eric

```
package ericadams.ftcscoringapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class ScoringScreen extends AppCompatActivity  {

Spinner CapBallSpinnerA;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> CapBallAdapterAA;

Spinner BeaconSpinnerA;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> BeaconAdapterA;

Spinner ParkedSpinnerA;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ParkedAdapterA;

Spinner CapBallSpinnerE;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> CapBallAdapterE;

Spinner BeaconSpinnerE;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> BeaconAdapterE;

Button CenterPlusA;
Button CenterMinusA;
Button CornerPlusA;
Button CornerMinusA;

Button CenterPlusD;
Button CenterMinusD;
Button CornerPlusD;
Button CornerMinusD;

Button ResetButton;

int CenterCountIntD = 0;
int CornerCountIntD = 0;

int CornerCountIntA = 0;
int CenterCountIntA = 0;
int AutoScoreIntA = 0;
int BeaconScoreIntA = 0;
int ParkedScoreIntA = 0;
int CornerScoreIntA = 0;
int CenterScoreIntA = 0;
int CapballScoreIntA = 0;

int DriverScoreIntD = 0;
int CenterScoreIntD = 0;
int CornerScoreIntD = 0;

int EndScoreIntE = 0;
int CapballScoreIntE = 0;
int BeaconScoreIntE = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scoring_screen);

    CapBallSpinnerA = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.CapBallSpinA);//Here --------------------------
    CapBallAdapterAA = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.CapBallAOptions,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    CapBallAdapterAA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    CapBallSpinnerA.setAdapter(CapBallAdapterAA);

    BeaconSpinnerA = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.BeaconSpinnerA);//Here --------------------------
    BeaconAdapterA = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.BeaconAOptions,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    BeaconAdapterA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    BeaconSpinnerA.setAdapter(BeaconAdapterA);

    ParkedSpinnerA = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ParkedSpinnerA);
    ParkedAdapterA = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.ParkedOptions,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ParkedAdapterA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ParkedSpinnerA.setAdapter(ParkedAdapterA);


    CenterMinusA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CenterMinusA);
    CenterPlusA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CenterPlusA);

    CornerMinusA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CornerMinusA);
    CornerPlusA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CornerPlusA);



    CenterMinusD = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CenterMinusD);
    CenterPlusD = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CenterPlusD);

    CornerMinusD = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CornerMinusD);
    CornerPlusD = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CornerPlusD);

    ResetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);



    CapBallSpinnerE = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.CapBallSpinnerE);
    CapBallAdapterE = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.CapBallEOptions,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    CapBallAdapterE.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    CapBallSpinnerE.setAdapter(CapBallAdapterE);

    BeaconSpinnerE = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.BeaconSpinnerE);
    BeaconAdapterE = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.BeaconOptionsE,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    BeaconAdapterE.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    BeaconSpinnerE.setAdapter(BeaconAdapterE);


    CapBallSpinnerA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView CapBallScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CapBallScoreA);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);



        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("thing",CapBallSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString());

            if (CapBallSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("On Floor")){
                CapBallScoreA.setText("5");
                CapballScoreIntA = 5;
            } else if (CapBallSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("On Center Goal")){
                CapBallScoreA.setText("0");
                CapballScoreIntA = 0;
                //txtValue.setText(Integer.toString(0));
            }

            AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            AutoScoreIntA = (CornerScoreIntA+CenterScoreIntA+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(AutoScoreIntA));
            TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    BeaconSpinnerA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView BeaconScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BeaconScoreA);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("thing",BeaconSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString());

            if (BeaconSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("1 Beacon")){
                BeaconScoreIntA = 30;
            } else if(BeaconSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("2 Beacons")){
                BeaconScoreIntA = 60;
            } else {
                //if(BeaconSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0 Beacons"))
                BeaconScoreIntA = 0;
            }
           // BeaconScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(BeaconScore));
            AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            AutoScoreIntA = (CornerScoreIntA+CenterScoreIntA+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            BeaconScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(BeaconScoreIntA));
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(AutoScoreIntA));
            TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    ParkedSpinnerA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView ParkedScoreA  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ParkedScoreA);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("thing",ParkedSpinnerA .getSelectedItem().toString());

            if (ParkedSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Half Center")){
                ParkedScoreIntA = 5;
                ParkedScoreA.setText("5");
            } else if(ParkedSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Full Center")){
                ParkedScoreIntA = 10;
                ParkedScoreA.setText("10");
            } else if(ParkedSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Half Corner")){
                ParkedScoreIntA = 5;
                ParkedScoreA.setText("5");
            } else if(ParkedSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Full Corner")){
                ParkedScoreIntA = 10;
                ParkedScoreA.setText("10");
            } else {
                //if(ParkedSpinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Not Parked"))
                ParkedScoreIntA = 0;
                ParkedScoreA.setText("0");

            }

            //ParkedScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(ParkedScoreIntA));

            //AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            AutoScoreIntA = ((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(AutoScoreIntA));
            TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    CenterMinusA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        TextView CenterBallCountLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterCountLabelA);
        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView CenterScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterScoreA);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);


        public void onClick(View v){
            CenterCountIntA = CenterCountIntA - 1;

            CenterScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(CenterCountIntA*15));
            CenterBallCountLabel.setText(Integer.toString(CenterCountIntA));


            CenterScoreIntA += (CenterCountIntA*15);
            AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            AutoScoreIntA = ((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(AutoScoreIntA));
                     TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));

        }
    });

    CenterPlusA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        TextView CenterBallCountLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterCountLabelA);
        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView CenterScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterScoreA);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);


        public void onClick(View v){
            CenterCountIntA = CenterCountIntA + 1;

            CenterScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(CenterCountIntA*15));
            CenterBallCountLabel.setText(Integer.toString(CenterCountIntA));

            System.out.print(CenterScoreIntA);

            CenterScoreIntA = (CenterCountIntA*5);
            AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            AutoScoreIntA = ((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(AutoScoreIntA));
            TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));


        }
    });

    CornerMinusA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        TextView CornerBallCountA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerCountLabelA);
        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView CornerScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerScoreA);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);


        public void onClick(View v){
            CornerCountIntA = CornerCountIntA - 1;

            CornerScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(CornerCountIntA*5));
            CornerBallCountA.setText(Integer.toString(CornerCountIntA));

            AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            CornerScoreIntA = (CornerCountIntA*5);
            AutoScoreIntA = ((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(AutoScoreIntA));
            TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));

        }
    });

    CornerPlusA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        TextView CornerBallCountLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerCountLabelA);
        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView CornerScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerScoreA);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);


        public void onClick(View v){

            CornerCountIntA = CornerCountIntA + 1;

            CornerScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(CornerCountIntA*5));
            CornerBallCountLabel.setText(Integer.toString(CornerCountIntA));

            AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            CornerScoreIntA += (CornerCountIntA*5);
            AutoScoreIntA = ((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(AutoScoreIntA));
            TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));


        }
    });

    //End of Autonomous Section

    ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        TextView CapBallLabelA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CapBallLabelA);
        TextView CapBallScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CapBallScoreA);
        TextView BeaconScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BeaconScoreA);
        TextView ParkedScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ParkedScoreA);

        TextView CornerScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerScoreA);
        TextView CenterScoreA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterScoreA);
        TextView CornerCountLabelA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerCountLabelA);
        TextView CenterCountLabelA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterCountLabelA);

        TextView CenterScoreD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterScoreD);
        TextView CornerScoreD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerScoreD);
        TextView CornerCountLabelD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CornerCountLabelD);
        TextView CenterCountLabelD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterCountLabelD);

        TextView AutoScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoScore);
        TextView DriverScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DriverScore);
        TextView EndScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EndScore);
        TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);

        public void onClick(View v){
            CapBallSpinnerA.setSelection(0);
            BeaconSpinnerA.setSelection(0);
            ParkedSpinnerA.setSelection(0);
            BeaconSpinnerE.setSelection(0);
            CapBallSpinnerE.setSelection(0);

            CapballScoreIntA = 0;
            CapballScoreIntE = 0;
            BeaconScoreIntE = 0;
            CornerCountIntD = 0;
            CenterCountIntD = 0;
            CornerCountIntA = 0;
            CenterCountIntA = 0;
            BeaconScoreIntA = 0;
            ParkedScoreIntA = 0;

            CapBallSpinnerA.setSelection(0);
            BeaconSpinnerA.setSelection(0);
            ParkedSpinnerA.setSelection(0);
            BeaconSpinnerE.setSelection(0);
            CapBallSpinnerE.setSelection(0);

            ParkedScoreA.setText("0");
            CapBallScoreA.setText("0");
            CapballScoreIntA = 0;



            BeaconScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(0));

            CornerScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(0));
            CornerCountLabelA.setText(Integer.toString(0));

            CenterScoreA.setText(Integer.toString(0));
            CenterCountLabelA.setText(Integer.toString(0));


            CenterScoreD.setText(Integer.toString(0));
            CenterCountLabelD.setText(Integer.toString(0));

            CornerScoreD.setText(Integer.toString(0));
            CornerCountLabelD.setText(Integer.toString(0));

            DriverScoreIntD = 0;
            DriverScoreIntD = (CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5);
            DriverScore.setText(Integer.toString(DriverScoreIntD));

            AutoScoreIntA = 0;
            AutoScoreIntA = ((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA);
            AutoScore.setText(Integer.toString(0));

            TotalScore.setText(Integer.toString((CapballScoreIntE+BeaconScoreIntE)+(CornerCountIntD)+(CenterCountIntD*5)+((CornerCountIntA*5)+(CenterCountIntA*15)+BeaconScoreIntA+ParkedScoreIntA+CapballScoreIntA)));




        }
    });








}

}
```

Unfortunately, I'm out of my 3000 characters for this page if I add my XML.  So, I included link to my Github Repo.  If it's still necessary, I think I can still make a "minimum".  From what I understand, I'd take my program and delete parts that have nothing to do with the problem so when you are reviewing the code, you don't have to look over it, correct?

So, I deleted all the unnecessary code from this post.

Thank you all!

https://github.com/FestiveInvader/FTCScoringApp(Classes Branch)
For minimum branch, go to Minimum branch.

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: all of code??????

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and edit your question so that it is possible to answer it in a meaningful way.

Comment: Okay, I have made a minimum code post.  I also included a github link to my code, which has three branches.  My current branch is Classes, however, I do have the minimum branch as well, which when loaded onto an android phone still replicates the problem.

Comment: Also, was the problem that I worded my question poorly and you didn't know what I was asking?  If so, here I go.  If not, I'll just clarify a little anyway.  My problem is that once I change either the beacon spinner or the capball spinner to a value, then I hit the reset button, somehow the autoscore text view is set to a value that is not 0.  Its usually around 20.  Then, I hit the reset button again, and it works!  So, I'm trying to figure out how and why the button doesn't work the first time.  Also, how to fix it would be nice too. ;)  Thanks